# Updating child objects in Google App Engine using DataNucleus JDO

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, entity, jdo

I have spent several hours trying to work this one out and I just can't seem to get my child entities to update despite trying several suggestions.  I have looked at the GAE documents extensively and I have tried placing things in transactions, tried making them "owned" objects and making them part of the "default fetch group."  The objects are correctly persisted in the datastore after running the dummy "populateDatastore" method below and I can retrieve them from the datastore with no issue.  When I make changes, those changes are not persisted, although I am using the setter methods so JDO picks up the changes.  I am not a Java expert, so I may be doing something really obviously wrong and I don't see it.

**Parent object**

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION, detachable = "true")
public class Parent {
  @PrimaryKey
  @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
  private Key key;

  @Persistent
  private String invitationCode;

  @Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true")
  private Child child;

  // additional ivars and getters and setters
}
```

**Child object**

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION, detachable = "true")
public class Response {

  @PrimaryKey
  @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
  private Key key;

  @Persistent(mappedBy = "child")
  private Parent parent;

  // additional ivars and getters and setters
}
```

**I have several methods to retrieve and save objects.**

```
public void persistParent(Parent p, boolean closeSession){
  manager = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
  manager.makePersistent(p);

  if(closeSession) {
    manager.close();
  }
}

public Transaction beginTransaction() {
  int retries = 3;
  manager = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
  Transaction tx = manager.currentTransaction();

  try {
    tx.begin();
  }
  catch(com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.CapabilityDisabledException e) {
    return null;
  }
  catch(Exception e) {
    return null;
  }
  return tx;
}

public boolean endTransaction(Transaction tx) throws Exception {
  int retries = 3;
  try {
    tx.commit();
  }
  catch(ConcurrentModificationException e) {
if (retries == 0) {
      throw e;
    }
--retries;
  }
  catch(com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.CapabilityDisabledException e) {
    if (retries == 0) {
      throw e;
    }
--retries;
  }
  catch(Exception e) {
    if (retries == 0) {
      throw e;
    }
    --retries;
  }
  finally {
    if(tx.isActive()) {
      tx.rollback();
    }
  }

  manager.close();

  return true;
}

public List<Parent> getParentWithID(String code, boolean closeSession) {
  Query q = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager().newQuery(Parent.class);
  q.setFilter("code == codeParam");
  q.declareParameters("String invitationCodeParam");

  List<Invitation> results = null;
  try {
    results = (List<Parent>) q.execute(code);
  } 
  finally {
    if(closeSession) {
      q.closeAll();
    }
  }

 return results;
 }
```

**Lastly, I have a dummy method to throw some data into the datastore for testing.  I add several children to the children list but for brevity's sake, I have cut out a lot of the redundant code.  I also persist several parent objects as well.**

```
Child c = new Child(arg1, arg2, arg3);
c.setSomeIVarForChild(arg1);
p = new Parent(arg1, arg2, arg3);
p.getChildList().add(c);
rsvpDao.persistParent(p, true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly what is the implementation behind "PMF.get()", but in case you are creating a new *PersistenceManagerFactory* on each get() - there is no need, you can just hold it as a static member.
If this is not the problem, try checking if you are using the same *PersistenceManager* for retrieving and updating the data objects: meaning only one call to *PMF.get().getPersistenceManager()* for the entire operation. In case you need to query for objects and then persist them later using a different *PersistenceManager*, you should [detach](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_1_1/jdo/attach_detach.html)

Comment: PMF is just the Google example for a Java singleton for the PersistenceManagerFactory.  I am holding it as a static reference so I know that I am using the same one.  It is interesting that I have to use a different workflow for getting the entity if I want to work on it (using detaching) than if I just want it for read-only access and that notating the class as above won't be enough of a clue for JDO.

Comment: So now that I am calling "detachCopy()" on the object I am retreiving, I am now getting "Object with id <> is managed by a different Object Manager."  I looked over my code, and I am closing my PM every time I use it, so I don't think it is a resource leak...I am not quite sure what is going on.

Comment: You can use JDOHelper.getPersistenceManager([your object]) and see if this is the same PM you are executing pm.detachCopy() for debug. Make sure you call detachCopy() when you have the object but before closing the PM that you used to retrieve it.

Comment: This is actually the proper solution if it weren't for the fact that there is inheritance involved.  I was reading the datanucleus docs and saw that the inheritance + app engine + detaching wasn't supported.

Comment: I have the same problem as David ->  "Object with id <> is managed by a different Object Manager." Any idea on how to fix this? I think I'm going to try:                      if(JDOHelper.getPersistenceManager(obj) != pm) {   jobs.add(JDOHelper.getPersistenceManager(obj).detachCopy(obj));
    } else {
     jobs.add(pm.detachCopy(obj));
    }

Answer (score 0):

Problem which I faced was my parent object primary key was "Key" object. Changing to to Long worked. Not sure what is the exact issue and how it solved the problem as I'm new to android and gae

Answer (score 0):

I've added the following and it fixed my issue:

```
if(JDOHelper.getPersistenceManager(obj) != pm) {
    logger.error("JDOHelper.getPersistenceManager(obj) != pm  ->     JDOHelper.getPersistenceManager(obj)[" +     JDOHelper.getPersistenceManager(obj).toString() + "]"
                            + " pm[" + pm.toString() + "]");
                    detatchedJob =     JDOHelper.getPersistenceManager(obj).detachCopy(obj);
                    jobs.add(detatchedJob);
                } else {
                    detatchedJob = pm.detachCopy(obj);
                    jobs.add(detatchedJob);
                }
```